# Cannot connect to Azure SQL Server using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, anaconda, pyodbc

Yet another post about an Azure SQL Server connection problem from Python I'm afraid.  I've been through multiple threads on this site, Microsoft's site and other links via Google but I cannot get this working.

I'm using the latest version of Anaconda (Python 3.6.6) and have ODBC driver version 17.2.0.1 installed.

Using the following script:

```
import pyodbc

server = server = 'myserver.database.windows.net,1433' #also tried prepending tcp:....
database = 'db1' #not the real db name
username = 'username@myserver' #also tried username@mydomain.com
password = '123456' #obviously not my real password!
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}' #also tried v13 ODBC driver and 'SQL Server' here

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';PORT=1433;SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: ('IM004', "[IM004] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_ENV failed (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Can anybody offer any insights please?

Comment: I don't see `PWD=` in your connection string.

Comment: Hi, yes, I've tried that and I think every permutation possible.  I've also tried using the DSN (which works fine for MS Access).  I think the error is at the Azure end but why should it be application specific if my IP address and port 1433 has been allowed on the server?  Must be something to do with the authentication but the error doesn't really help and neither does Google

Comment: Microsoft's ODBC Driver for SQL Server does not support a `PORT=` parameter. You already have `,1433` appended to your `server` value (where it should be, if needed), so try removing `PORT=1433;` from your connection string.

Comment: I've tried, that, also with and without 'tcp:' prepended. I tried to cover as many of my permutations in comments but couldn't cover everything. To me it looks like an issue with pyodbc and active directory authentication as in the DSN (which works for Access): "Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated"

Comment: It's a bit of a long shot, but instead of `Authentication=(whatever)` you could try `Trusted_Connection=no` along with your `UID` and `PWD` parameters to see if that works.

Comment: Thanks Gord, that didn't help, I'm certain that the connection string isn't the problem and that it's an Azure permissions or authentication problem. What's strange is that Access/ODBC is fine so there's something specific to the way odbc authenticates that isn't built into pyodbc

Answer (score 4):

I know this answer is a little late, but in case anyone else needs help.

The official Azure documentation, shows parameters which are different to what is actually required:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-2017

The solution that did work for me was to access the connection string in the database portal in my Azure dashboard.

If you navigate to the database instance you're trying to connect to and select Overview:
[image]

Then on the right hand side you should find Connection strings:
[image]

And then you should be able to select the ODBC connection string which only requires that you replace your password:
[image]

I suspect that the thing that catches most people out is selecting the appropriate driver. As you can see in this string and in the pyodbc documentation you have to specify which driver to use based on what your DB is running on:

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows

This solution worked first time for me, provided that I had added my IP to the DB firewall.

Answer (score 1):

all the rest same
run `print(pyodbc.drivers())`
driver= '{SQL Server}'` try this solution. then I can connect with the AZURE SQL database

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with the Python syntax and I'm unfamiliar with the error you're receiving, but Azure Documentation does indicate that you need to create a rule to allow connections from your computers public IP before you can interrogate any Azure hosted DB's with Python.

You might have already done this, but as it's not mentioned as something done in the question, it might be worth clarifying anyway.

[Azure Firewall Rule Set Up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-portal#create-a-server-level-firewall-rule)

Comment: Thanks for that.  I can already connect via Server Management Studio, and via MS Access over an ODBC connection using the same driver from where I'm sat (office LAN which is already in the Azure firewall rule list), is your suggestion specific to Python/application specific?  From reading that link it would suggest that as I can access the server from SMS and MS Access over ODBC that pyodbc should work?

Comment: Seems that it is for connection of any sort from external locations, so you should be okay for this then.